# New table which I can filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Are there any tricks that could get me from table 1 to table 2. I don't see a solution at this time. Is it doable?

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tJO7.png)

[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1SYK.png)

Thank you

I tried transpose and pivot but it doesn't help.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula:

```
=query({BYROW(B1:B,lambda(each,if(each="","",XLOOKUP("class",INDIRECT("b1:b"&ROW(each)),INDIRECT("a1:a"&ROW(each)),,,-1)))),A1:C},"Select Col1,Col3,Col4 where not Col3 contains 'Class' AND Col2 is not null label Col1 'Class Name'",1)
```

It creates a first row (inside the formula itself with BYROW) with a XLOOKUP which finds the previous (or upper) Class (that's the final -1 in XLOOKUP), and then makes a QUERY of the 4 columns (1st with this Classes and the other three) filtering Type columns (not containing "Class"). If you want also to have the other column just add "Col2" after "Select Col1,"

[image]

See it working [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QZR3scSYej78Y5atphe_5EGMes8JQrL_RJRRp-QHexg/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thank you so much Martin . Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are seeking:

[image: sample]

This formula will lookup the Name column for `"Class A name"` and `"Class B name"`, and return the data between...

1. `"Class A name"` and `"Class B name"`,
2. `"Class B name"` and end of data.

```
=LAMBDA(SOURCE,A,B,HEADERS,
 LAMBDA(NAME,TYPE,NR,
  LAMBDA(INDEXA,INDEXB,INDEXE,
   LAMBDA(DATAA,DATAB,
    {HEADERS;DATAA;DATAB}
   )(FILTER(SOURCE,ROW(NAME)>INDEXA,ROW(NAME)<INDEXB),
     FILTER(SOURCE,ROW(NAME)>INDEXB,ROW(NAME)<INDEXE))
  )(XMATCH(A,NAME),XMATCH(B,NAME),COUNTA(NAME)+1)
 )(INDEX(SOURCE,,1),INDEX(SOURCE,,2),INDEX(SOURCE,,3))
)(A1:C7,"Class A name","Class B name",{"Class name","Group name","Nr students group"})
```

Comment: Thank you as well Ping. You gave me some useful idea as well. Appreciate your input